# How to make an English sentence from a first-order logic formula with unbound variables?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'll first quote the problem from *'Computability and Logic'* by Boolos, Burgess, Jeffrey.

> **9.3** Consider a language with a two-place predicate **P** and a one-place predicate **F**, and an interpretation in which the domain is the set of persons, the denotation of **P** is the relation of parent to child, and the denotation of **F** is the set of all female persons. What do the following amount to, in colloquial terms, under that interpretation?
>
> (**a**) $\exists z\exists u\exists v(u \neq v \ \land \mathbf Puy\ \land \mathbf Pvy\ \land \mathbf Puz\ \land \mathbf Pvz\ \land \mathbf Pzx \ \land  \lnot \mathbf Fy  )$

I left out b, since it's quite similar to a.
Now, I understand how to make  a colloquial English sentence from a statement like this: $\forall a \forall b \ (\mathbf Pab \implies \mathbf \lnot \mathbf Pba)$. For example, this could be *'No one is a parent of his or her parent.'* But in the problem above, x and y are unbound variables. How do I deal with this? Are they perhaps implicitly meant to be universally bounded? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How would you phrase it if you used $y$ as the name of a specific person, and you were saying something about $y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have unbound (free) variables, then you should just refer to those variables.

That is, just like we *define* predicates by sayhing something like:

$P(x,y)$: '$x$ is a father of $y$'

we can likewise express complex formulas with free variables, e.g.

$\exists y(P(x,y) \land P(y,z))$: 'There is someone who has $x$ as a father, and who is a father of $z$'

Comment: So your example and the problem above are propositions whose truth depends on which variables you put in, or in which way you bind the variables, unlike my example?

Comment: @StevenWagter  Yes, as long as you have free variables, the formula is not a sentence, i.e. not something you can evaluate and assign a truth-value to. It is only when you quantify (bind) all the free variables that it becomes a sentence with a truth-value.  Your formula is no different. It has free variables $x$ and $y$, and hence is not a sentence; just a formula.  But you can still *express* that formula.